# Limitations of Spark ML's Linear Regression

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I am using the [Linear Regression estimator](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html) in a pipeline.

In my original set-up, I trained the model using a dataset with 3774 rows and 500 features. Spark handled this task without error.

However, I run into a problem with a newer set of training data, which has 6072 rows, but the same number of features. When training the model, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:212)
    at breeze.optimize.OWLQN$$anonfun$3.apply(OWLQN.scala:95)
    at breeze.optimize.OWLQN$$anonfun$3.apply(OWLQN.scala:93)
    at breeze.linalg.DenseVector$CanZipMapKeyValuesDenseVector.map(DenseVector.scala:563)
    at breeze.linalg.DenseVector$CanZipMapKeyValuesDenseVector.mapActive(DenseVector.scala:571)
    at breeze.linalg.DenseVector$CanZipMapKeyValuesDenseVector.mapActive(DenseVector.scala:554)
    at breeze.optimize.OWLQN.adjust(OWLQN.scala:93)
    at breeze.optimize.FirstOrderMinimizer.initialState(FirstOrderMinimizer.scala:49)
    at breeze.optimize.FirstOrderMinimizer.iterations(FirstOrderMinimizer.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.optim.QuasiNewtonSolver.solve(NormalEquationSolver.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.optim.WeightedLeastSquares.fit(WeightedLeastSquares.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression.train(LinearRegression.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression.train(LinearRegression.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:96)
    at lasso.Lasso.main(Lasso.java:279)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

The only thing that has changes in the number of observations, not the number of features. Is there a known limit for the input size that the Linear Regression can handle?

Comment: can u put your code ?